# Error en Angular 7 al abrir la aplicación con IE11

Tags: angular7

Tengo una aplicación en Angular 7 que me esta dando errores en IE11 y no se me carga.
El archivo `tsconfig.json` es el siguiente:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Y el archivo `polyfills.ts` esta tal y como viene por defecto.

Esta dejó de funcionar a partir de la instalación del modulo ngx-img-max (redimensionado de imagenes) por una de sus dependencias, el modulo pica.

Al abrir la aplicación con IE11 y ver la consola, me aparece un error en la siguiente instrucción:

```
const DEFAULT_PICA_OPTS = {
  tile: 1024,
  concurrency,
  features: [ 'js', 'wasm', 'ww' ],
  idle: 2000
};
```

El error dice que se esperaba ':' ya que concurrency no tiene valor.

He intentado arreglarlo usando polyfills pero llevo poco tiempo con angular y me pierdo un poco.
¿Alguien me puede decir que esta pasando? ¿Se puede solucionar con polyfills?

He intentado incluso actualizar a las ultimas versiones del modulo y sus dependencias pero sigue dando el mismo error y me estoy volviendo loco.

Comment: creo que el parametro **concurrency** necesita ser tipado o ponderado. No tiene valor, pero lo tendrías que tipar **undefined**. Puede que ese sea el error

Comment: @menredo No, es un problema de que la sintaxis no es aceptada por IE

Comment: ¿ y se os ocurre porque puede ser ? ¿ o si se puede solucionar con algun polyfill ? porque se supone que el modulo es compatible con IE10+ (o al menos eso dicen ellos)

Answer (score 0):

He eliminado el módulo anterior, pues este creaba miniaturas de imagenes en cliente, y al final voy a guardar las imagenes con su tamaño original.
Al hacer esto, ha salido un nuevo error aun mas complejo:

```
SCRIPT1002: Error de sintaxis
Archivo: vendor.js, Línea: 23948, Columna: 5
```

Esto es lo que hay en la linea indicada:

```
return new (Function.bind.apply(Function, Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__spread"])([void 0], fnArgNames.concat(fnBody))))().apply(void 0, Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__spread"])(fnArgValues));
```

La configuración sigue siendo la que indicaba anteriormente, pero he probado a meterle todos los archivos polyfills del es7 y nada, sigue dando error en esta linea.
¿Alguna idea?